# How to get owin context in MediaTypeFormatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm storing per-request data in Owin Environment. Everywhere in the framework I'm able to get Owin context via `Request.GetOwinContext()` extension.

But in MediaTypeFormatter I have no access to HttpRequest, HttpContext or something like that. `HttpContext.Current` is not desirable solution.

I've already tried to use `GetPerRequestFormatterInstance`, but it's called only for response serialization, and not for request deserialization.

`IContentNegotiator` is not called also.

Answer (score 0):

In general getting request information from within a formatter is a known limitation in Web API and `GetPerRequestFormatterInstance` was a workaround created to support, as you figured, only the response side...the core issue here is with `System.Net.Http` (Which Web API depends on) library's `HttpContent` not providing a backpointer to the corresponding request/response...in ASP.NET [`vNext`](https://github.com/aspnet/home) I am guessing this should not be an issue...in any case I am interested in knowing more about your scenario so that it can help us in future design...